# Java getter and setter for a date field

Tags: java

I am beginning Java and I have been ask to write a class myDate. Such a class has fields for year, month and day.

I should use the following syntax to set the date:

```
setDate(long timeElapsed)
```

I know that I can do the following:

```
Date tempDate = new Date();
long lngDate = tempDate.getTime();
System.out.println("lngDate: " + lngDate);
```

How do I calculate the "long timeElapsed" parameter from a given year, month and day?

Now, I should use GregorianCalendar to display the date, for which I have done the following:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
System.out.println("Year: " + cal.YEAR);
System.out.println("Month: " + cal.MONTH);
System.out.println("Day: " + cal.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

But the results I get are as follow:

```
Year: 1
Month: 2
Day: 5
```

How can I use GregorianCalendar to display a date in myDate class? I have been working on this issue for a while without success.

I will very much appreciate your feedback.

Respectfully,
Jorge Maldonado

Comment: But timeElapsed has no meaning outside of a given timezone.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Where does `year, month, day` come from? Are you asking how to calculate the elapsed time between today’s date and another date? If so, search Stack Overflow as this has been handled many times already. Also, you are using troublesome old leacy classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the following method to get the date as a long from a calendar:

```
cal.getTimeInMillis()
```

Here is the corresponding class:

```
public class MyDate {

  public void setDate(long timeElapsed) {
     final GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
     cal.setTime(new Date(timeElapsed));

     this.year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     this.month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     this.day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  }

  public long getLong() {
     final GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(this.year, this.month, this.day);
     return cal.getTimeInMillis();
  }

  private int year, month, day;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calendar.YEAR as well as MONTH and DAY_OF_THE_MONTH are constants to use in get() method. so

```
System.out.println("Year: " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println("Month: " + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
System.out.println("Day: " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

does what you need.

BTW on top you do not need to create new Date to get time value:

```
long lngDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("lngDate: " + lngDate);
```

value is the same. When new Date created it uses System.currentTimeMillis()

PS. Just keep in mind cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) returns month number -1. Jan is month 0, Feb is month 1 and so on.